# Why do I need to use NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED="0" if it's insecure

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I am having trouble connecting with node https library to a website with:

ESET SSL Filter CA - Certificate.

At the moment, I worked around it with `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED="0"` but this is not very secure.

Can anybody point me in the right direction, why the https library doesn't work like one would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly verify that your SSL certificate is valid or properly configured or not by using OpenSSL's command.

```
openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port>
```

If OpenSSL is not installed then you can check it directly on web from [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html)

Comment: Yeah my admin did bad ssl certificates.